# Moving Windows 10 from C drive (on HDD) to SSD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup

I just bought an SSD. I have a lot of programs installed, so I want to avoid reinstalling Windows.

Partitioning scheme:

HDD: (2 partitions):
<sub>C (Windows): ~500G - Free ~400GB

D (data): ~1.5T - Free ~100GB</sub>

SSD: (1 partition):
<sub>E: 250GB</sub>

I read a few posts and tutorials explaining that I need to backup all of my data on D to some other "backup" devices, but since I do have ~1.4G data and I don't have any backup device to move them to, so I can't merge C and D. Is there any way that I can move everything on C to SSD (E) and make it bootable, then merge the free spaces from C into D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have tried different tools and none of them worked as expected so far, the thing is that most of them will create some visible FAT32 system disks after cloning the Windows disk (which should be hidden), and made the windows driver not C (which, again screw up some of the setting that needs to read from C: drive instead of new driver letter). Below is a working solution that I found so far:

1. Download [EasyUS Todo Backup](https://www.easeus.com/backup-software/)
2. Install it, choose the Trial for faster speed (or, if you choose free version, it will take a lot longer, believe me)
3. Select Clone Disk, just clone your C: disk to SSD
4. Wait and let it finish.

*Now up to this step, everything is done. You can continue to step 7. However, it will leave no visible FAT32 system disk and the new windows will be assigned to the next driver letter (i.e: E:, F: etc), follow the below steps to change these.*

5. DO NOT RESTART, now shut down your computer.
6. Unplug the OLD HDD, make sure it's not connected to the mainboard.
7. Restart your PC, enter your BIOS settings and choose to boot from SSD (it will be the only one now - or you can skip this step).
8. Now after you are in, your new windows will be assigned to C: drive. Make sure everything works.
9. Shut down again, plug in your HDD.
10. After booting, go to "This-PC", and remove the windows on the HDD.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only 100gB on your C: drive, it will fit easily on the SDD and you have no problem.

Download the excellent – and free – MiniTools Partition Wizard and follow the instructions at  [How to Migrate OS to SSD/HD | MiniTool Partition Wizard Tutorial](https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/migrate-os-to-ssd-hd.html) – it’s as simple as that

Comment: Sorry, Chris; don't know how I overlooked that. Monday morning :-/  Then it's no problem at all (+1)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the solution i need. 1 Follow up question: After selecting "To Replace the System Disk", there are 2 options: "replace my system disk with another hard disk" and "Move my OS to another hard disk". It asks to select "replace the system disk". Why not the other? Thanks

Comment: As far as I understand it, option 1 is when you want to replace your C: drive with another, presumably larger, and the program would have to copy it temporarily to another drive, then copy it back to the new one when you install it. But you definitely want option 2.

Comment: so i have tried both of the options, none worked. They both created some FAT32 system drives and make the SDD unbootable (after changing the BIOS boot). I found another solution, will add it below.

Comment: Strange, as I have used that a few times now with no problems at all. Please do post what you found as an answer (and I will upvote it), as that will help others in future. Don't forget to accept your own answer. Glad you found something ;-)

Comment: Thanks I updated my answer above. Sorry not sure why your solution didn't work, but it was a good start for me to dig more to find my own answer. Thank you.